# Jquery pagination which dont load all data at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, pagination

I am searching this for an hour but I dont get any perfect solution for it. I want pagination which doesnot load all data at once and loads only what are currently showing on the page. I dont want to refresh whole page while going from 1st page to any other page of pagination. And I am preffering to use JQuery. Just give me any good pagination link. I dont have tables I have divisions for pagination

Answer (score 0):

This would be pretty simple to do by hand, no libraries needed. You'd put an event listener on the buttons

```
$('#button').on('click', function(){
    changePage($(this).data('page-number');
}

var changePage = function(pageNumber)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'whatever.php',
        data: {
           page_number: pageNumber
        },
        success: function(r){
            var html = //build html based on ajax respone
            $('#page-wrapper').empty().append(html);
        }
    });
}
```

Realistically though if there are not going to be a huge amount of pages, you should get the data for ALL the pages and simply store it in Javascript variables and then access those variables when you click a page number.

Comment: Its an ecommerce website so data might be much more